# Why I commit to set the state's data to null, the component state do not change util I refresh the page?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

In my `store.js`:

```
  state: {
  ...

  user_info: LocalStorageUtil.get('user_info')
  },

  mutations: {
    set_user_info_null(state){
      state.user_info = null
    }
  }
```

In my component:

```
    // in the template
    <div v-if="user_info" class="welcome">
          <a @click="welcome_username">欢迎您,{{user_info.username}}!</a>/<a @click="logout">退出</a>
    </div>

// in the script
data(){
  return {
    user_info: this.$store.state.user_info,
    ...

  }

methods: {
  ...

  ... // in the logout method
  LocalStorageUtil.clear('user_info')
  this.$store.commit('set_user_info_null')  // store set to null
```

You see, I clear the `user_info` first, and then Vuex to commit `set_user_info_null`. The Vuex's state user_info will be set to `null`.

[image]

but however, in the Component's data the user_info still is the Object:

[image]

---

**EDIT -1**

If I use the code:

```
import { mapState } from "vuex";
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState("user_info")
  }
};
```

I got a error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(map)')

in this line:

```
computed: {
  ...mapState("user_info")
},
components: {   // in this line
...
```

Comment: Please include info about how you are using the state in your component.

Comment: @JacobGoh See my updated post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part is problematic in your component

```
data(){
  return {
    user_info: this.$store.state.user_info,
    ...

  }
```

You are declaring a local component state that is separated from the Vuex store. When you update Vuex store, this won't change.

The right way is by using [mapState](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/state.html)

```
import { mapState } from "vuex";
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState(["user_info"])
  }
};
```

It would be like you are passing `user_info` as a `prop` to this component. When Vuex store is updated, this component will be updated as well.

Comment: Sir, I don't know how to config the `.bablerc` so the `...mapState("user_info")` will report error.

Comment: perhaps this will help you https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/

Comment: sorry. I made a mistake. it should be `...mapState(["user_info"])`. `mapState` accepts only array or object

Comment: And how about the `[Vue warn]: Computed property "user_info" was assigned to but it has no setter.` error?

Comment: you need setter only when you are assigning value to `user_info` directly in your component. So i guess you have some operation like `this.user_info = 'something'` or `v-model='user_info'` in your code. You can add a setter by following the example(Two-way Computed Property) in https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/forms.html

Answer (score 0):

In the newer( higher than v.2.3.4 ) version Vue.js the code will check the set, if in your code has `this.user_info=xxx` :

You can check the [source code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/instance/state.js#L229).

So, first I will recommend you change the `this.$store.state.user_info=xxx` replace of `this.user_info=xxx`.

Second you should take a look at the [Two-way Computed Property](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/forms.html)

```
computed: {
  message: {
    get () {
      return this.$store.state.user_info
    },
    set (value) {
      this.$store.commit('set_user_info_null')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hmm.. in the setter, instead of changing store value directly, it should commit mutation or dispatch action